# Highchart only wants "y" element in JSON data?

Tags: highcharts

First here is my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/H242k/1/

It seems as though if I feed Highcharts a JSON data, it wants the "value" to be an element "y". But the JSON data I'm pulling is an arbitrary value element.

In my JSFiddle, if I change `"Results of Last Year"` to `"y"`, it works. How do I make it so that it will take `"Results of Last Year"` as the chart's value?

Also, if I structure my data like this, how do I access the category (cat1, cat2, cat3, etc) in the xAxis label?

Answer (score 1):

Highcharts is reading your structure and creating a chart with it.  You can't just come up with whatever structure you want and expect Highcharts to know what to do with it.  The available options are very well documented at http://api.highcharts.com/.  To define a point, look at the http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data.  If you want to use text instead of numbers for your xAxis, use categories http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.categories.

In your case, something like this will work:

```
  $('#container').highcharts({
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['cat1', 'cat2', 'cat3', 'cat4', 'cat5', 'cat6', 'cat7', 'cat8', 'cat9', 'cat10', 'cat11', 'catr12']
        },
        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5,106.4,129.2,144.0,176.0,135.6,148.5,216.4,194.1,95.6,54.4]
        }]
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/H242k/2/

Comment: Thank you Barbara. So something that I didn't add is that I'm feeding the Highcharts data using AJAX. The AJAX returns my data in JSON format. So from what I'm seeing in your solution is that I should split the JSON data up using Javascript so that I can set the categories and value?

Comment: Yep, you'll need to post process the data to get it into the format HighCharts needs.